# I'm seeing "use of undeclared identifier" error, can someone tell me how to fix it?

Tags: c++

I received error messages for the following code. I am new to C++ so I couldn't see what's the problem. Thank you so much.

header file(VGMap.h):

```
#ifndef VGMAP_H
#define VGMAP_H

namespace Game
{
 struct AdjListNode{
   int data;
   AdjListNode *next;
  };
 struct AdjList{
   AdjListNode *head;
 };
 struct Graph{
   int V;
   AdjList *arr;
 };
 class vgmap{
   public:
   AdjListNode *newAdjListNode(int);
   Graph *createGraph(int);
   void addEdge(Graph*,int,int);
   void printGraph(Graph*);  
 };
```

}#endif

VGMap.cpp:

```
#include "VGMap.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

namespace Game
{
  AdjListNode* vgmap::newAdjListNode(int data){
    AdjListNode *nptr=new AdjListNode;
    nptr->data=data;
    nptr->next=NULL;
    return nptr;

  }
  Graph* vgmap::createGraph(int V){
    Graph *graph=new Graph;
    graph->V=V;
    graph->arr=new AdjList[V];
    //initialize with NULL (e.g root=NULL)
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
        graph->arr[i].head=NULL;
    }
    return graph;
  }
  void vgmap::addEdge(Game::Graph *graph, int src, int dest){
    AdjListNode *nptr=newAdjListNode(dest);
    nptr->next=graph->arr[src].head;
    graph->arr[src].head=nptr;
    //connect from dest to src (since undirected)
    nptr=newAdjListNode(src);
    nptr->next=graph->arr[dest].head;
    graph->arr[dest].head=nptr;
  }
  void vgmap::printGraph(Game::Graph *graph){
    for(int i=0;i<graph->V;i++){
        AdjListNode *root=graph->arr[i].head;
        if(i==4||(i-4)%5==0){
          cout<<std::endl;
        }
        else if(i%5==0){
          cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        while(root!=NULL){
          if(root->data==i+1){
            cout<<root->data<<" ";
            //i=i+1;
          }
            root=root->next;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#include "VGMap.h"

using Game::AdjListNode;
using Game::AdjList;
using Game::Graph;
using Game::vgmap;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
  int totalVertices=30;
    Graph *graph;
    graph=createGraph(totalVertices);
    //connect edge
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=10;i<14;i++){
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=15;i<19;i++){
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=20;i<24;i++){    
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=29;i>25;i--){
      addEdge(graph,i,i-1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      addEdge(graph,25-i*5,25-(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      addEdge(graph,1+i*5,1+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      addEdge(graph,2+i*5,2+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      addEdge(graph,3+i*5,3+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      addEdge(graph,4+i*5,4+(i+1)*5);
    }
    printGraph(graph);
}
```

This is the error message I received:

```
main.cpp:47:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'createGraph'
    graph=createGraph(totalVertices);
          ^
main.cpp:50:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
      ^
main.cpp:53:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
      ^
main.cpp:56:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
      ^
main.cpp:59:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
      ^
main.cpp:62:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
      ^
main.cpp:65:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,i,i-1);
      ^
main.cpp:68:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,25-i*5,25-(i+1)*5);
      ^
main.cpp:71:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,1+i*5,1+(i+1)*5);
      ^
main.cpp:74:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,2+i*5,2+(i+1)*5);
      ^
main.cpp:77:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,3+i*5,3+(i+1)*5);
      ^
main.cpp:80:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'addEdge'
      addEdge(graph,4+i*5,4+(i+1)*5);
      ^
main.cpp:82:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'printGraph'
    printGraph(graph);
    ^
13 errors generated.
```

Comment: Why are you calling member functions like they are free functions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please first extract a [mcve] from your code. This example must be contained inline in your question.

Comment: I see a `Game::vgmap::createGraph` function, but no `::createGraph` function. So I agree with your compiler.

Comment: This should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no functions defined `createGraph` or `addEdge`.  There are however methods called `vgmap::createGraph` and `vgmap::addEdge`.

Still, you can't call these methods like this because you would need to first create an instance of `vgmap`, then call the methods on that object.

Since these methods don't act on any internal data, change their definitions to `static`:

```
 class vgmap{
   public:
   static AdjListNode *newAdjListNode(int);
   static Graph *createGraph(int);
   static void addEdge(Graph*,int,int);
   static void printGraph(Graph*);  
 };
```

And then you can call them with the full name without having to create an instance of `vgmap`:

```
graph=vgmap::createGraph(totalVertices);
...
vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i-1);
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid this answer still leaves OP clueless as to what static functions are and why using them resolves their problem. And what better alternatives may exist.